# Is the word "coin" a proper bitcoin term?

Tags: transactions, terminology

I have noticed that some people speak of "coins".  As far as I can tell, by "coin" they mean a `transaction output`.  Is this a correct understanding?  Is it helpful to use the word "coin"?

Answer (score 1):

Right.  The statement "Alice has 5 coins" could be more precisely phrased "Alice controls the private keys for some set of addresses, to which are directed some set of transaction outputs with a total value of 5".  But that's a lot more cumbersome.

Comment: Actually that's not how I understand it.  To me, "Alice has 5 coins" would not convey any information about total value... it would mean: "There are 5 unspent outputs in the blockchain payable to private keys held by Alice".  Only if you would add up all the values of those 5 outputs would you know Alice's wealth.  You could say "Alice has 3 coins, totalling 10 BTC, consisting of a 3.5 BTC coin, a 5 BTC coin and a 1.5 BTC coin"